# How do I know that this equation does not have a general solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this exercise:

**Exercise:**

If possible, find the general solution is one of the following equation:

$$
y'' + 3ty' + t^2y = 0, -\infty < t < \infty
$$
where $y$ is a function of $t$.

**My solution:**

Set $x = \dfrac{1}{2}t^2$. Then $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = t$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt} = t \dfrac{dy}{dx}$ and $\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2} = \dfrac{d}{dt}\big(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt}\big) = \dfrac{dy}{dtdx}\dfrac{dx}{dt} + \dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = t^2\dfrac{dy}{dx} + \dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{d}{dt}t = t^2\dfrac{dy}{dx} + \dfrac{dy}{dx}$. If we substitute this into the equation we get
$$
t^2\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \dfrac{dy}{dx} + 3t^2\dfrac{dy}{dx} + t^2y = 0
$$

I'm not able to solve the equation from this point and the textbook says that there is no general solution.

**Question:** How do I *know* that there is no general solution? How do I know that I can stop looking?

Comment: It is about impossible to really know. We do have methods for the simple equation $y'=f(x)$, by the Risch algorithm, following the Liouville theorem on antiderivatives, but it takes a computer and a CAS system to apply it. I assume that these methods can be generalized to ODEs, but I am not sure this has been done.

Comment: What does it even mean "not having a general solution"? In this case the differential equation has globally defined solutions for every set of initial conditions. In the book they probably want to say that there is no way of getting a closed form general solution, in terms of usual functions. For instance Wolfram provides a solution in terms of special functions (HermiteH, Hypergeometric1F1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WolframAlpha's result, and can express in terms of Confluent Hypergeometric Function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%22%2B3ty%27%2Bt%5E2y%3D0)